# How to print multiple tabs of jtabbedpane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am working on a project that uses Java Swing in Netbeans and Im stuck. I want the end user to be able to click print and the program print all (5) tabs of the jtabbedpane. My current print method only prints one tab and I cannot figure out how to get it to print all 5. All of the things I've seen online to try to help have only posted a link to a tutorial form Oracle or something which is hard to follow and doesnt usually have an answer for me.

Here is the code for the print method (Not my original code completely):

```
JTabbedPane yourComponent = jTabbedPane1;
    PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PageFormat preformat = pjob.defaultPage();
    preformat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
    PageFormat postformat = pjob.pageDialog(preformat);
//If user does not hit cancel then print.
    if (preformat != postformat) {
        //Set print component
        pjob.setPrintable(new Printer(yourComponent), postformat);
        if (pjob.printDialog()) {
            try {
                pjob.print();
            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                ex.getMessage();
                Logger.getLogger(InputsMVN.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the active tab is printed. So what about iterating through all tabs, make them active and call your print method? Set active tab using `setSelectedIndex` method

Comment: Consider using a reporting engine, like Jasper Reports instead - if you MUST use your current approach, consider having a look at the `Book` interface

Comment: @IvanPronin you are right. I didnt realize that it had to be made active. Im pretty new to Swing and not super experienced with deep level Java. Thank you!